# 3 divs inside container div do not allow wrapping

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 div's inside a container div for a fixed top navbar, how can I stop one div from sliding underneath another, which makes the nav bar taller. Here is my code, its using bootstrap. Essentially the navbar-header div is sliding underneath the header-full-title div, i want it to force it to resize since its an img-responsive.

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-header-full">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="header-full-title img-responsive">
                    <img src="~/Content/img/MTC_logo_header.png" class="img-responsive" />
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    @*<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="~/Content/img/MTC_logo_header.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    </a>*@
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">


                    <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">OUR STORY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">VISIT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">DIRECTORY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">CONDOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">APARTMENTS</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="navStyle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EVENTS</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownMTC pull-right">
                                <li><a href="#">YOGA ROCKS THE PARK</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">MONDAY NIGHT MOVIES</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">HORSES OF HONOR</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">THURSDAY IN THE PARK</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">EVENT SHUTTLE</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">HOLIDAY LIGHTS FESTIVAL</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">NEWS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>

    </nav>
```

### CSS

```
       .header-full-title {
       float: left;
       padding-left: 20px;


         }
```

Comment: what are the dimensions of `~/Content/img/MTC_logo_header.png`?

Comment: 396px x 67px its img-responsive as well

Comment: Does this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwbh1sfx/) accurately demo your problem?

Comment: Exactly the issue I am seeing.

Comment: Your best bet is to use `@media` queries in css to target certain breakpoints to reduce the width of your `.header-full-title`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sure does. I already have a bunch in there I added,sounds like a good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@media is probably your best bet. Making sure the nav bars only move and shrink when @media is activated.

Above suggestions are just as good as well.

Answer (score 0):

I went with media queries works great just had to move the navbar a bit height wise and reduce padding here and there.